# How to improve XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT() written query performance?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with following query to get required result. But the query takes long time to run in live environment.Query as follows

```
SELECT a.int_key,main_number,b.local_number,dia.diag_number,a.clm_key
FROM clamp a
INNER JOIN polins b
ON a.ins_id=b.ins_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT int_key, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,MD.VAL,',').EXTRACT('//text()')
  ORDER BY int_key).GetClobVal(),',') diag_number
  FROM dia D
  INNER JOIN ms_dia MD
  ON MD.dia_key=D.dia_code
  GROUP BY int_key
  ) dia ON a.int_key =dia.int_key
WHERE a.int_key NOT IN
  (SELECT int_key FROM table1
  );
```

I think subquery in from clause `RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,MD.VAL,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY int_key).GetClobVal(),',')` took long time to run. I already tried with listagg but following error was raise `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`. Can anyone rewrite the above query effectively.

Comment: Copying the `int_key NOT IN ...` condition into the `dia` subquery might speed it up.

Comment: Have you looked into `XMLSERIALIZE`?  Also, depending on how your tables are indexed, you may be doing the expensive XML operation on needless rows.  Have you tried moving the GROUP BY and XML operations to the outer select, making the query one level without the subquery?

Comment: @Del Using ```XMLSERIALIZE``` will bring comma seperated value for particular column? I checked in google but that function is indented for other purpose other than what i expect.

Comment: @Nvr XMLSERIALIZE allows you to easily take XML and cast it to different data types.  It also helps making it human readable if that is important to the situation.